# Php cannot pass session values across pages (webmatrix)

Tags: php, session, session-variables, webmatrix

i'm started to use webmatrix and now iam using php starter site template.

in this template you cant login. i searched all codes than i found it doesnt pass session. maybe it creates but dont pass to other pages.

if there is user(logon.php):// this works session has value

```
if ($statement->num_rows == 1)
{

    $statement->bind_result($uid,$uname);
    $statement->fetch();
    $_SESSION['userid']=$uid;
    $_SESSION['username']=$uname;
    echo $_SESSION['username']; // yes its printing username
    header ("Location: index.php");
}
```

check(header.php):

```
  if (logged_on())
    {
        echo '<li><a href="/logoff.php">Sign out</a></li>' . "\n";
    }
```

logged_on function: // this is not working

```
function logged_on()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['userid']); //empty
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use webmatrix or something like that you need to specify session stored folder.

just paste this code to top of your pages. webmatrix creates session but doesnt store it.

```
session_save_path($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/tmp");
```

after this you need to create tmp folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `session_start()` at the top of any scripts in which you want to be able to use session variables.